# Cuba library: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: gcc, compilation, x86, arm64, cuba

I'm working on a M1 and trying to compile a cpp code with libquadmath and the Cuba library.
On the site (http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/) is said that
I can easily make use of GNU C compiler, problem is (and here I'm guessing) I get the following error I'm not sure why.

```
ignoring file ./lib/libcuba.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_llVegas", referenced from:
      _main in ccucELGn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any guesses?
Thanks everyone

Comment: This seems to be a followup to [Undefined symbols clash x86\_64 and arm64 architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72184477) (maybe after solving some of its problems?)  Still seems like a case of mixing x86-64 and AArch64 binaries, which could maybe be avoided by building everything from source for one ISA or the other.

Comment: Ok got it, still this procedure sounds new to me but I'll search for some more information!